# drawing an image in java swing following a sinuous pattern ( a river)

Tags: java, algorithm, swing

I have this bufferedImage of a wooden log and i want it to float down the river. However the river has a sinuous pattern like an S shaped river. do you guys know of any mathematical algorithms or structures so I can draw the image floating down the river smoothly and keeping within the confines of the river?

the wooden log is considered a jcomponent and I am drawing on top of the river which is a background image. I use jlayeredpanes to keep them separate.

any ideas/ suggestions?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Any code to share? The image at least? Nothing?

Comment: I have tried nothing because I am stuck. i was wondering if there was any mathematical structure or algorithm? my code would not help much i think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *think* you want two things to happen to the log:

- its center needs to be aligned with the center of the river
- its angle needs to be aligned with that of the river as well.

Suppose your river's equation looks like this (it's a horizontal sinus river):

`y = sin(x/100 * PI/2) * 100`

so that

```
x=0,   y=0
x=100, y=100
x=200, y=0
x=300, y=-100
... and so on ...
```

More generically,

```
y = sin(x/Cx * PI/2) * Cy
```

- Large Cx yields longer curves
- Large Cy yields more of a Y-axis spread

The center of your log should just follow the same equation:

```
y = sin(x/Cx * PI/2) * Cy
```

The angle of your log (aka angle of the river's path at any given point) is simply the derivative of the above (and Lord help me with math here):

```
alpha = dy/dx = cos(x/Cx * PI/2) * Cy * PI/2 * 1/Cx
```

And then, of course, look at [Graphics2D documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html?java/awt/Graphics.html) to figure how to draw & rotate things in Java.

Comment: thanks for the help! i was looking it into further and i stumbled upon spline interpolation. do you think that will help?

Comment: Seems spline interpolation would be appropriate if you wanted to bend your log to follow the river... but even in this case, you could just use the river's formula (interpolation assumes formulas is unknown). Separately, a bending log would probably look kinda funky :)